# How can I find total number of signups in a week?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django build in User model have one-to-one relation with UserProfile model. I have to count number of signups in a week. How can I do this?. Thanks in advance for your addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `date_joined` in User model, it mean A datetime designating when the account was created. Is set to the current date/time by default when the account is created.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.date.today() 
startDate = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
endDate = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
users = User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=[startDate, endDate])
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for answering. But my issue is with to count all my signups of one week. Can you please elaborate how i can make it possibe?

Comment: hi @ming chi! i think the startdate is not so important you can just use:endDate = date_joined + datetime.timedelta(days=7) and users = User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=[date_joined, endDate])